# How do I fix homepage issue in MVC 5 when i add bootsrap lumen theme?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Please help with this as I want to customize the navbar and replace the names from default such as application and index etc to my application, home page and etc. 
[image: image of a webpage after adding bootstrap lumen theme no nav bar and no proper content displayed]
**Model Page Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
namespace VidlyMovies.Models
{
public class Customers
{
public int Id  { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
}
}
```

**LayoutpageCode**

```
 @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Random";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2> @Model.Movies.Name</h2>
```

**Controller Page Code**

```
namespace VidlyMovies.Controllers
{
public class MoviesController : Controller
{
// GET: Movies/Random 
public ActionResult Random()
{
 var movie = new Movies() {Name = "Avengers"};
 return View(movie);
}
}
}
```

Comment: Bootstrap 4 might cause this... check your version.

Comment: Show the code with the navbar. Your title is about a theme problem, but then you ask about changing nav bar links, then you include seemingly unrelated code snippets.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ldg_3F8yZW6Ni45rGC3ZSWgP30ou6uoP2E3SALO7IsQ/edit?usp=sharing @SteveGreene please find the link with all default page code Thanks

Comment: It looks like your header has not totally rendered (missing the list of menu options). If you look at the console (F12) are their script errors?

Comment: @SteveGreene thank steve, i looked in console but there are no error. can you suggest what needs to be done from your point of view to make nav bar visible ? or customize new one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, assuming this is Bootstrap 3 and your "css" bundle is loading it, their example [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/examples/navbar/) could be used. Taking a shot at integrating your code I would try:

```
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <!-- Wrap your banner, app name etc. in a link back to home page -->
            <a href="@Url.Action("Vidly", "Home", new { area = "" })" class="navbar-brand" title="Return to home page.">
                <!-- I am using a font awesome icon plus text. You can use a bootstrap glyph or a banner, image, etc. -->
                <span><i class="fa fa-home"></i> My App Name</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <!-- This is where you put your menu items. It will collapse if screen is small. The id is important to link above. -->
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active">@Html.ActionLink("Vidly", "Vidly", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
  @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```